# audioplayers package does not play audio on Samsung phones (A8 and some others) but works on emulator and other brand phones

Tags: android, flutter, dart, audio, audio-player

**The plugin audioplayers does not play audio on Samsung phones (A8 and some others) but the same code plays on all emulator and other brand phones like MI (Xiaomi Phones).**
*Plugin*: https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers/

*Code to Reproduce*
The code used is the code mentioned in the EXAMPLE section of the GIT repository of the package.
I have just downloaded and made a project out of it.
https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/tree/master/example

[image]

**Log Errors and Output**

*Samsung A8*

```
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 147305 (msec)
D/ViewRootImpl@6846f3MainActivity: ViewPostIme key 0
D/ViewRootImpl@6846f3MainActivity: ViewPostIme key 0
D/ViewRootImpl@6846f3MainActivity: ViewPostIme key 0
D/ViewRootImpl@6846f3MainActivity: ViewPostIme key 0
D/ViewRootImpl@6846f3MainActivity: ViewPostIme key 0
D/ViewRootImpl@6846f3MainActivity: ViewPostIme key 0
D/ViewRootImpl@6846f3MainActivity: ViewPostIme key 1
D/ViewRootImpl@6846f3MainActivity: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@6846f3MainActivity: ViewPostIme pointer 1
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): native_setup
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): constructor
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): setListener
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): setVolume: left 1.000000 right 1.000000
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): MediaPlayer::setVolume(1.000000, 1.000000)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): setAuxEffectSendLevel: level 0.000000
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): MediaPlayer::setAuxEffectSendLevel(0.000000)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): setParameter: key 1400
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): MediaPlayer::setParameter(1400)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): setVolume: left 1.000000 right 1.000000
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): MediaPlayer::setVolume(1.000000, 1.000000)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): setLooping: 0
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): MediaPlayer::setLooping
V/MediaHTTPService( 3247): MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@6b0d2e3): Cookies: null
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): setVolume: left 1.000000 right 1.000000
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): MediaPlayer::setVolume(1.000000, 1.000000)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): setLooping: 0
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): MediaPlayer::setLooping
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): setVideoSurfaceTexture
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): prepareAsync
V/MediaHTTPService( 3247): makeHTTPConnection: CookieManager created: java.net.CookieManager@81d24e0
V/MediaHTTPService( 3247): makeHTTPConnection(android.media.MediaHTTPService@6b0d2e3): cookieHandler: java.net.CookieManager@81d24e0 Cookies: null
D/MediaHTTPConnection( 3247): setReadTimeOut = 15000ms
D/MediaHTTPConnection( 3247): setReadTimeout with 15000ms
I/System.out( 3247): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out( 3247): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getPlaybackSettings: 1.000000 1.000000 0 0
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): setPlaybackParams: 1:1.000000 1:1.000000 1:0 1:0
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): setPlaybackSettings: 1.000000 1.000000 0 0
D/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 3247): tagSocket(96) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
I/MediaHTTPConnection( 3247): response code = 200
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): message received msg=200, ext1=10973, ext2=0
W/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): info/warning (10973, 0)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): back from callback
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): message received msg=3, ext1=2, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): buffering 2
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): back from callback
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): MediaPlayer::notify() prepared
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): back from callback
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): invoke 68
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): start
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): start
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): message received msg=300, ext1=0, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): Received SEC_MM_PLAYER_CONTEXT_AWARE
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): back from callback
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 0 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): message received msg=3, ext1=3, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): buffering 3
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): back from callback
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): message received msg=6, ext1=0, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): unrecognized message: (6, 0, 0)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): back from callback
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 0 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 78 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): message received msg=211, ext1=0, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): unrecognized message: (211, 0, 0)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): back from callback
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): message received msg=211, ext1=0, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): unrecognized message: (211, 0, 0)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): back from callback
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): message received msg=211, ext1=0, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): unrecognized message: (211, 0, 0)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): back from callback
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): message received msg=211, ext1=0, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): unrecognized message: (211, 0, 0)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): back from callback
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 214 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 418 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 624 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 829 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): message received msg=3, ext1=100, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): buffering 100
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): back from callback
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 1037 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 1243 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 1448 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 1653 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 1859 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 2067 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 2273 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 2480 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 2686 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 2891 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 3096 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 3304 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 3512 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 3719 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 3926 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 4133 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 4342 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 4551 (msec)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 4758 (msec)
D/ViewRootImpl@6846f3MainActivity: ViewPostIme pointer 0
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): getDuration_l
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getDuration: 210077 (msec)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): getCurrentPosition: 4963 (msec)
D/ViewRootImpl@6846f3MainActivity: ViewPostIme pointer 1
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): stop
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): stop
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): message received msg=8, ext1=0, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): unrecognized message: (8, 0, 0)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): back from callback
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): message received msg=211, ext1=0, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): unrecognized message: (211, 0, 0)
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): back from callback
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): reset
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): reset
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): message received msg=211, ext1=0, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): notify(211, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
V/MediaPlayer( 3247): resetDrmState: mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
V/MediaPlayer( 3247): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
V/MediaPlayer( 3247): resetDrmState: mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
V/MediaPlayer( 3247): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 3247): release
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): setListener
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): disconnect
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): destructor
V/MediaPlayerNative( 3247): disconnect
```

*Xiaomi A4*

```
Waiting for Redmi 4 to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53510/_zZdPLPOQlY=/ws
Syncing files to device Redmi 4...
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI(31188): env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI(31188): JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI(31188): env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI(31188): JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
V/BoostFramework(31188): BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@33db57e
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI(31188): env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI(31188): JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI(31188): env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI(31188): JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
```

Comment: You should open a bug report on https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers where the author would suitably address the issue.

Comment: thanks @bluenile, i have a bug posted to them already.https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/issues/703